# TikZ: How to rotate a matrix (of nodes)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, nodes, rotating

Please consider the following TikZ code:

```
% aligning text in node: node[align=left] only in latest 2010 tikz:
% http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/-tikz-option-for-ragged-left-text-in-node
% or use minipage inside node: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/
% or also parbox: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Topics
%% note: parbox and minipage width 5em - will extend beyond the minimum width=5em!
% or use /tikz/text ragged:
% http://old.nabble.com/Equal-width-nodes-within-%22matrix-of-nodes%22--td15266855.html
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]
    \matrix (xA) [anchor=west,text ragged]
    {% 
        \node(xA1) [draw,right,minimum width=5em] {horizon1} ;  \\
        \node(xA2) [draw,right] {horiz2} ;  \\
%       \node(xA3) [draw,anchor=west,minimum width=5em] {\begin{minipage}{5em}hor3\end{minipage}} ; \\
        \node(xA3) [draw,anchor=west,minimum width=5em] {\parbox{5em}{hor3}} ;  \\
    };
    \matrix (yA) [below left=of xA]
    {% 
        \node(yA1) [draw,right,rotate=270] {vert1} ;    &
        \node(yA2) [draw,right,rotate=270] {vert2} ;    &
        \node(yA3) [draw,right,rotate=270] {vert3} ;    \\
    };
    \begin{scope}[rotate=270]
    \matrix (zA) [rotate=270,below left=of yA]
    {% 
        \node(zA1) [draw,right] {horvert1} ;    \\
        \node(zA2) [draw,right] {horvert2} ;    \\
        \node(zA3) [draw,right] {horvert3} ;    \\
    };  
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It generates the following image:

[image: tikz matrix hor/vertical]

I would like to achieve something like the `yA` case - except, I'd like the texts to go 'vert1','vert2','vert3' from right to left (opposite of what is shown) - which would correspond to the `xA` graphic being rotated for 270 degrees.

So that is what I'm trying to do with the `zA` case - however, as one can see, there is no rotation whatsoever!

Does this mean that a matrix of nodes cannot be rotated in TikZ? If not, how can I rotate such a matrix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah well - I guess this is the answer, pg 487 of the pgfmanual.pdf:

> **Rotations and scaling.** The matrix node is **never rotated** or shifted, because the current coordinate
>   transformation matrix is reset (except for the translational part) at the beginning of \pgfmatrix. **This
>   is intentional** and will not change in the future. If you need to rotate the matrix, you must install an
>   appropriate canvas transformation yourself.
>
> However, nodes and stuff inside the cell pictures can be rotated and scaled normally.

... Also, from [matrix nodes with sloped option? - pgf-users](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pgf.user/1296):

> It does say in the manual that **it isn't possible** (in section 16.2
>   "Matrices are Nodes"), and that the transformation matrix is reset at
>   the beginning of a matrix. The (internal) use of `\halign` precludes any
>   kind of fancy transformations. It would be pretty hard to do matrices
>   without using `\halign`.

... HOWEVER ...

... [matrix nodes with sloped option? - pgf-users](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pgf.user/1296) also says:

> Indeed.
>
> However, you can do the following: Put the whole node inside a
>   `tikzpicture`, which in turn you put in a node that has the sloped
>   option. Something like
>
> ```
> ... (A) -- (B) node[midway,sloped] {\tikz \matrix ...;};
> ```

which means that the code above can be modified like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]
    \matrix (xA) [anchor=west,text ragged]
    {% 
        \node(xA1) [draw,right,minimum width=5em] {horizon1} ;  \\
        \node(xA2) [draw,right] {horiz2} ;  \\
%       \node(xA3) [draw,anchor=west,minimum width=5em] {\begin{minipage}{5em}hor3\end{minipage}} ; \\
        \node(xA3) [draw,anchor=west,minimum width=5em] {\parbox{5em}{hor3}} ;  \\
    };
    \matrix (yA) [below left=of xA]
    {% 
        \node(yA1) [draw,right,rotate=270] {vert1} ;    &
        \node(yA2) [draw,right,rotate=270] {vert2} ;    &
        \node(yA3) [draw,right,rotate=270] {vert3} ;    \\
    };
    \node (zzA) [rotate=270,below left=of yA] {
        \tikz \matrix (zA) 
        {% 
            \node(zA1) [draw,right] {horvert1} ;    \\
            \node(zA2) [draw,right] {horvert2} ;    \\
            \node(zA3) [draw,right] {horvert3} ;    \\
        };  
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

... which will finally result with the originally desired image:

[image: tikz hor/vertical matrix rotation OK]

Comment: The problem with subpictures is that you can't reference the `(zA1)`, `(zA2)` and `(zA3)` nodes from the outside, except if you use `remember picture` (but then you must check your node names don't conflict with those from other pictures…